# Pass global variable to php file through AsyncTask in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am currently populating a RrecyclerView from a remote database but wish to only query the database for dates based on a users ID. I have the userID assigned as a global variable on the LoginActivty of the app but I'm not sure where to pass that information to the php page from my DateActivity.

My Code for the DateActivity is as follows:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static String globex_num;

// CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
private RecyclerView mRVDateList;
private AdapterDate mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_date);
    //Make call to AsyncTask
    new AsyncFetch().execute();
}

private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(DateActivity.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            url = new URL("thephpfile.com");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
        try {

            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // setDoOutput to true as we recieve data from json file
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;


                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (result.toString());

            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //this method will be running on UI thread

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        List<DataDate> data=new ArrayList<>();

        pdLoading.dismiss();
        try {

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

            // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                DataDate dateData = new DataDate();
                dateData.date= json_data.getString("date");
                data.add(dateData);
            }

            // Setup and Handover data to recyclerview
            mRVDateList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.dateList);
            mAdapter = new AdapterDate(DateActivity.this, data);
            mRVDateList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mRVDateList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(DateActivity.this));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(DateActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Please don't dump your entire codebase into the question... only put the part(s) that you believe are relevant to the problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by passing it though the link.

```
url = new URL(www.thephpfile.php?userID=" + LoginActivity.userID);
```

At the start of the php file I did the following:

```
$userID = $_GET['userID'];
```